# reading database dump file into R

Tags: database, r

I am trying to figure out how to read database dump file into a table in *R*.

Here is the first line of the file:

`{ "id" : { "id" : "43" }, "type" : "Account::Private", "full_name" : "Joe Doe" }`

I need to parse it into a table with the appropriate column headers.

I only know `read.table`, `scan`, and basic commands for nicely formatted data sets.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:

My db-dump looks something like this:

`{  {"id" : { "id" : "43" }, "type" : "Account::Private", "full_name" : "Joe Doe" },
         {"id" : { "id" : "44" }, "type" : "Account::Private", "full_name" : "Jane Doe" },
         {"id" : { "id" : "45" }, "type" : "Account::Private", "full_name" : "John Doe" }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database-dump looks like a JSON structure. I'm assuming multiple rows are wrapped as a list, i.e. between "[" and "]".

This snippet

```
install.packages('rjson')
library(rjson)
s <- '[  {"id" : { "id" : "43" }, "type" : "Account::Private", "full_name" : "Joe Doe" },
         {"id" : { "id" : "44" }, "type" : "Account::Private", "full_name" : "Jane Doe" },
         {"id" : { "id" : "45" }, "type" : "Account::Private", "full_name" : "John Doe" }]'
js <- fromJSON(s)
d <- data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(js), ncol=3)))
names(d) <- c('id', 'type', 'full_name')
d
```

gives

```
  id             type full_name
1 43 Account::Private   Joe Doe
2 44 Account::Private  Jane Doe
3 45 Account::Private  John Doe
```

If you post a full example of the data, I can perhaps write a more robust snippet (now the number of columns and header names are hard-coded).

Comment: thank you! I went to check documentation on `json` and found that you can read the whole data file using `fromJSON` command.
In my case multiple rows are wrapped into '{ }', curly braces. Could you please, tell me how to read my entire file?

Comment: Can you perhaps post a more representative sample of the data, including the beginning and the end?